# How to convert the image to JSON using node formidable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to upload a image using node formidable. But when I use, ctx.req.files it results in undefined. Any suggestions for this ?

I've used ctx.req.file, ctx.body.files also

Comment: add code also. so we can help you out.

Comment: router.post("/file-validations", (ctx, req, res) => {
    var jsonData = ctx.req.files[{}];
    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    console.log(jsonContent)
    var buff = new Buffer(jsonContent).toString("base64")
    var data = jsonContent.text;
    console.log(data)

Comment: I'm using koa body parser. Can I use koa parser for parsing multipart form data ?